# Speech Recognition Hangs on ApiController

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, speech-recognition

I have a service using mvc and in this case I have a controller that is implementing the apicontroler I'm calling a post from another project and passing it a stream. I then get the string and work on it.
This method runs and returns the correct value but then I don't get anything where I called it. It looks like it's working but nothing happens.

Here's the code.

```
result = new List<string>(); 
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(); 
Task loadingStream = (Request.Content as StreamContent).CopyToAsync(stream);

loadingStream.Wait();

stream.Position = 0;

SpeechRecognitionEngine _appRecognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-US"));

_appRecognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(SpeechRecognized);

_appRecognizer.SetInputToWaveStream(stream);

_appRecognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(@"C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\grammar1.srgs")); 
RecognitionResult recognitionResult = _appRecognizer.Recognize();

_appRecognizer.SpeechRecognized -= SpeechRecognized;

return recognitionResult != null ? recognitionResult.Text : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you call _appRecognizer.RecognizerAsync()? Check out document [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx).